# Am I supposed to first release my iOS game and THEN submit it for Facebook review?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want my game to be able to post to your Facebook wall. For this, I made a Facebook Developer app, and fed the API key to the SDK. It works.

I noticed that there is a "Submit for app review" button in the Facebook app page. Since all I want is to post to someone's wall (which I managed to do already), is it ***necessary*** to do this? Can I simply leave the Facebook app alone, or is there like a time period before it gets deleted or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope - you need to "Submit for app review" and getting it approved by Facebook before you sent your app for publication on the Apple App store. In fact at the moment your app is running in sandbox mode - that means that it works only using your FB account or the FB account of any other developer/tester you might have added to your app via the Facebook Developers website. If you try to perform a FB login within your app using a different account, at this stage you will receive an error (you can easily test it).

If your concern is about - how will they test my app if that is not release yet? Well they won't test it - the only thing that the Facebook team will check is that your Facebook App page is complies with all their requirements - therefore be careful to upload a logo of the right size, without a background, etc (they have a series of rules to follow).